# Scripting Efficiency: One script for multiple children, or one script for each?

Tags: lua, scripting, roblox

In case the title isn't explanatory enough, I have a lot of parts with scripts, and many of those parts' scripts are clones. It seems to me that it would be more efficient and use less processor time to have just one script monitoring all the parts that use the same script within a group/model, than numerous scripts running simultaneously to accomplish the same task(s).

Structurally, it's one script (child) per part (parent) vs. one script (parent) for many identical parts and their identical functions (children).

Also, in terms of maintenance and changes, it is much easier to alter one script than many. In one group, for example, I have 80 parts with the same script running for each. To alter, say, how much damage a brick causes on touch for 80 or more scripts is a pain.

Thoughts and advice appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are a few considerations you can make for performance when deciding one script vs many... Like, are there any infinite loops or heavy processessing that can be done in a centralized place? Is this code more simple when in a self contained model versus a big complicated manager class? What is your personal preference for code structure? etc.

But if your concern is maintanability, then Roblox has a feature to make this a lot easier. It's called [Packages](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/roblox-packages). It allows you to make a model, publish it as a package, and then make clones of it. If changes are made to any of the clones, then you can publish those changes and you can instantly update all of the clones at once.

Comment: For the scripts mentioned, they are constantly active waiting for a touch, so that's an infinite loop of sorts, right?

Yes, it's much simpler when it's one-to-one instead of manager class, but isn't that pretty much inevitable?

My personal preference is efficiency and maintainability. I shall have to look at packages, I think, as it seems to be an elegant solution for some scenarios. If I knew a LOT more about LUA, I might be able to see how it would be usable across the board but, at this time, replacing the master class script with packages would mean making multiple packages.

Comment: Also, I want to minimize script-induced lag.

Comment: If you're using Touch events, then those aren't infinite loops, those are event subscriptions. Those are just functions that fire when an event is invoked in the engine. They are very lightweight. You can always profile performance using the [MicroProfiler](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/MicroProfiler)

Comment: As always, so appreciative of your help! Thanks!

Comment: Hi Kylaaa, I need to communicate with you privately regarding some Roblox issues, but I don't know how. Can't message you here, my friend request on Roblox hasn't been accepted. Could you please contact me (@ru_gr8ful)? Thanks!